# Why does my pawn sometimes return with items only?

Tags: dragons-dogma

My pawn returns from adventuring with other players in two ways:

- with the name of who has been using her, Rift Crystals, a rating, possibly an item or some equipment, and a comment
- with nothing more than some small items, typically the kind she can gather herself

When I'm using other people's pawns, I can either gift them equipment, or I can release them with a single-item gift, which will cause them to return with Rift Crystals, a rating, a comment, etc. I don't see any other way to gift other pawns items.

What causes her to return with just items, and where does she get the items from? (She'd better not be stealing them!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the game itself renting your pawn.  This happens even in offline mode (seriously, disconnect your PS3 from your internet entirely and you'll still get "rents").  This is basically a method to ensure that EVERYONE accumulates Rift Crystals.

Comment: I think you're right :) Accepting this as the answer unless someone can come up with a better answer that includes references

Comment: This is in fact the correct answer. I can attest to it from three months on the road driving a semi-truck and having no access to internet for my PS3 while playing this game.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if the pawn is hired then you get rift crystals regardless, I have been having problems with the page telling me who hired my pawn and how many crystals I got for it not showing up, but I'm going to assume that if the pawn died or fell off a cliff or something and they didn't release the pawn, then I keep the items that he had from the adventure he went on with the other Arisen, and it won't show me who it was, seeing as I didn't get a rating or anything, but that is pure speculation, I still get several random items so it might be what he had at the time of his departure form their game.

Comment: Yea but what I meant was if I hire a pawn, they get the rift crystals if it dies or gets released, but if it dies, I don't get to give a gift, rate, or comment. So maybe they won't receive the page telling me who hired their pawn, they just get the forfeit items and the rift crystals.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like no player hired your pawn, so you get the "consolation prize" of whatever she manages to scrounge up. That would explain why she doesn't tell you who hired her, doesn't have a comment, wasn't rated, and has low value items. Since the game cannot guarantee that a pawn will be hired by a real player, there must be a mechanic in place for when no player hired them. Sending them back with a couple items would be a reasonable solution.

Comment: I don't think this is the case... she's used quite frequently and once has returned with items-only directly after she returned from another player (was sleeping 2 days in a row to wait for the Black Cat to forge something for me). Also, the # of items I get varies, and the number of items is not related to how often I sleep (so far it has been between 1 and 4)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, pawns don't die that often with the exception of the beginning of the game.

The game gives you riff crystals each time you rest at an inn. But, if you rest back to back, sometimes you get nothing.

The amount of crystals will depend on your level. Also, if the pawn dies, it will keep some of the items that are in its inventory, but not material items or weapons unless gifted.

If someone uses your pawn and your pawn gets killed you will still see who had it and everything. 
You just will not have a rating or comment just that they used it and the crystals the pawn got before it died.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was wen they die, or become
Forfeit, as when other peoples pawns die for me
I get no option to rate or gift.